# Django prefetch_related query not working as required, troubleshooting needed

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have two simple Django models:

```
class PhotoStream(models.Model):
    cover = models.ForeignKey('links.Photo')
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Photo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    which_stream = models.ManyToManyField(PhotoStream)
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_photo_to_location, storage=OverwriteStorage())
```

Currently the only data I have is 6 photos, that all belong to 1 photostream. I'm trying the following to prefetch all related photos when forming a photostream queryset:

```
queryset = PhotoStream.objects.order_by('-creation_time').prefetch_related('photo_set')
for obj in queryset:
    print obj.photo_set.all() 
#print connection.queries
```

Checking via the debug toolbar, I've found that the above does exactly the same number of queries it would have done if I remove the `prefetch_related` part of the statement. It's clearly not working. I've tried `prefetch_related('cover')` as well - that doesn't work either.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it? My goal is to get all related photos for every photostream in the queryset. How can I possibly do this?

---

Printing `connection.queries` after running the for loop includes, among other things:

`SELECT ("links_photo_which_stream"."photostream_id") AS "_prefetch_related_val", "links_photo"."id", "links_photo"."owner_id", "links_photo"."image_file" FROM "links_photo" INNER JOIN "links_photo_which_stream" ON ("links_photo"."id" = "links_photo_which_stream"."photo_id") WHERE "links_photo_which_stream"."photostream_id" IN (1)`

*Note: I've simplified my models posted in the question, hence the query above doesn't include some fields that actually appear in the output, but are unrelated to this question.*

Comment: Can you post the queries that are being generated?

Comment: @solarissmoke: added

Comment: Thanks. Can you see other queries in which each photo is being fetched individually?

Comment: Do you have `through` table in `which_stream` relation?

Comment: @GwynBleidD: yes I do, since it's a m-2-m relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some of the extracts from [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

> `**prefetch_related**`, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the `‘joining’` in Python.

And, some more:

> ```
> >>> Pizza.objects.all().prefetch_related('toppings')
> ```
>
> This implies a `self.toppings.all()` for each Pizza; now each time `self.toppings.all()` is called, instead of having to go to the database for the items, it will find them in a **prefetched QuerySet cache** that was populated in a single query.

So the **number of queries** you see will always be the same but if you use `prefetch_related` then instead of hitting the database on for each `photostream` it will hit the `prefetched QuerySet cache` that it already built and get the `photo_set` from there.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean here. You could measure the total time taken while querying in both the cases but for that you need to have some significant data. What `prefetch_related` will do for you is save the round-trips to the database itself.

Comment: I specifically mean any way of objectively measuring that the roundtrips to DB are indeed being saved (since the SQL query count won't change, like you explained). How would I know what I implemented actually works?

Comment: You can look at the query itself (along with posting it in your question) The query would have something which looks like `prefetch_related_val`.

Comment: You need to print `connection.queries` after running the for loop. And you can obtain `connection` using `from django.db import connection`.

Comment: Thanks for the assist. Added the excerpt to the question (check). `prefetch_related_val` does seem to be in there. I suppose that closes the question? I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I am glad to have been of help.

Comment: @AKS not sure I agree with you here. `prefetch_related`, if used properly *will* reduce the number of database queries, and so you should see a reduction in queries logged by `django-debug-toolbar` (which logs DB hits). If you're not then there is something wrong - most likely that you are doing another query later on which makes the prefetched data useless.

Comment: @solarissmoke: It does reduce the database queries. The queries the OP is seeing are the ones being made to the `prefetched cache` (as you can see in the OP) and not to the database and that's the whole purpose of using `prefetch_related`. Obviously if the OP goes further and tries to access some other field on the `photo` it will result in another query.